# Who are the three infants who talk at their cradle period?

Tags: miracles

I heard a speech about hazrat eeshah (A.W).

In the bayan

> Hazarat eeshah (A.W) is one of the three infants in the history who
>   talk at their cradle period

It's in quran that eeshah (A.W) talked at his cradle period. I want to know , Who are the remaining two?

Add some references to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The hadith of [the three who spoke from the cradle](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/261880) doesn't name the other two, but does describe their stories:

- A pious man named Juraij was accused of fathering a child with a prostitute; he prayed, then asked the infant for the name of his real father, to which the child answered.
- A woman was nursing her infant and saw a well-to-do man, and prayed for her child to grow up like him; the child then prayed not to grow up like him.  Then she saw a woman, accused of prostitution and theft, and the mother prayed for her child not to grow up like her; the child then prayed to grow up like her.  The infant then explained the wisdom therefrom to her mother.

Comment: Also check the tafseer (ibn-Katheer) of Surah Al-Buruj (HQ, Chapter 85) where the child exhorts its mother to bear the tribulation for the sake of the Truth.

Answer (score 3):

The hadith in the question above is a Sunni Hadeeth and although I found some other Sunni Ahadeeth saying the infants talking at their cradle were 4 or 6, but anyway I do not know if any of these Ahadeeth if is considered an authentic also to Shia brothers.

Note. This answer comes from *Shia perspective*:

---

To this point I can only say one of the infants talking at the cradle was the witness that defended Joseph --peace be upon him-- when he ran away from Zuleikha:

> قَالَ هِيَ رَاوَدَتْنِي عَن نَّفْسِي ۚ وَشَهِدَ **شَاهِدٌ مِّنْ
>   أَهْلِهَا** إِن كَانَ قَمِيصُهُ قُدَّ مِن قُبُلٍ فَصَدَقَتْ وَهُوَ
>   مِنَ الْكَاذِبِينَ / وَإِن كَانَ قَمِيصُهُ قُدَّ مِن دُبُرٍ فَكَذَبَتْ
>   وَهُوَ مِنَ الصَّادِقِينَ
>
> He said: She sought to make me yield (to her); and a witness of her
>   own family bore witness: If his shirt is rent from front, she speaks
>   the truth and he is one of the liars: / And if his shirt is rent from
>   behind, she tells a lie and he is one of the truthful. [12:26,27]

A Hadeeth from Imam Sadiq --peace be upon him-- addresses this happening (only the related part is translated):

> علي بن إبراهيم، قال: حدثنا أبي، عن بعض رجاله، رفعه، قال: قال أبو عبد
>   الله (عليه السلام): «لماهمت به و هم بها، قامت إلى صنم في بيتها، فألقت
>   عليه ملاءة  لها، فقال لها يوسف: ما تعملين؟ قالت: القي على هذا الصنم
>   ثوبا لا يرانا، فإني أستحي منه، فقال يوسف: فأنت تستحين من صنم لا يسمع و
>   لا يبصر، و لا أستحي أنا من ربي؟! فوثب وعدا، و عدت من خلفه، و أدركهما
>   العزيز على هذه الحالة، و هو قول الله تعالى: وَ اسْتَبَقَا الْبابَ وَ
>   قَدَّتْ قَمِيصَهُ مِنْ دُبُرٍ وَ أَلْفَيا سَيِّدَها لَدَى الْبابِ.
>   فبادرت امرأة العزيز، فقالت للعزيز: ما جَزاءُ مَنْ أَرادَ بِأَهْلِكَ
>   سُوءاً إِلَّا أَنْ يُسْجَنَ أَوْ عَذابٌ أَلِيمٌ فقال يوسف للعزيز: هِيَ
>   راوَدَتْنِي عَنْ نَفْسِي وَ شَهِدَ شاهِدٌ مِنْ أَهْلِها **فألهم الله
>   يوسف أن قال للملك: سل هذا الصبي في المهد، فإنه يشهد أنها راودتني عن
>   نفسي، فقال العزيز للصبي، فأنطق الله الصبي في المهد ليوسف**، حتى قال:
>   إِنْ كانَ قَمِيصُهُ قُدَّ مِنْ قُبُلٍ فَصَدَقَتْ وَ هُوَ مِنَ
>   الْكاذِبِينَ وَ إِنْ كانَ قَمِيصُهُ قُدَّ مِنْ دُبُرٍ فَكَذَبَتْ وَ
>   هُوَ مِنَ الصَّادِقِينَ فلما رأى قميصه قد تخرق من دبر قال لامرأته:
>   إِنَّهُ مِنْ كَيْدِكُنَّ إِنَّ كَيْدَكُنَّ عَظِيمٌ ثم قال ليوسف:
>   أَعْرِضْ عَنْ هذا وَ اسْتَغْفِرِي لِذَنْبِكِ إِنَّكِ كُنْتِ مِنَ
>   الْخاطِئِينَ و شاع الخبر بمصر، و جعل النساء يتحدثن بحديثها و يعذلنها 
>   و يذكرنها، و هو قوله تعالى: وَ قالَ نِسْوَةٌ فِي الْمَدِينَةِ
>   امْرَأَتُ الْعَزِيزِ تُراوِدُ فَتاها عَنْ نَفْسِهِ قَدْ شَغَفَها
>   حُبًّا».
>
> ... So Allah inspired to Yusuf to say to the ruler that ask from this
>   infant in the cradle, the infant will bear witness that she was
>   seeking to make me yield (to her), so Aziz asked the infant and Allah
>   made the infant talking for the sake of Yu
>   suf ...
>
> source: البرهان في تفسير القرآن، ج‏3، ص: 169,170

Comment: good answer, one child is at the period of  hazrat yousuf(A.W) and the other?